# removing values from each element in a list in R

Tags: r, list

I was wondering if somebody could help with this problem. I have a list coming out from a function similar to the following:

```
lis<-vector("list",3)
lis[[1]]<-c(1,2,3)
lis[[2]]<-c(1,2,3)
lis[[3]]<-c(1,2,3)
```

so it looks like

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3
[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

What I want to do is remove, for example, the first element from each component of the list so it ends up like:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 3
[[2]]
[1] 2 3
[[3]]
[1] 2 3
```

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: `lapply(lis, '[', -1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply()` and do the index function for each element of the list. The index `-1` means ***without the first element***:

```
lis <- list(a=1:3, b=11:13, c=21:23)
lapply(lis, '[', -1)
# $a
# [1] 2 3
# 
# $b
# [1] 12 13
# 
# $c
# [1] 22 23
```